# 3 formulários em um único botão submit

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Boa tarde, estou com um código em *html* e *js* em que preciso fazer um submit em 3 formulários usando apenas um botão, isso porque estão em cardboards diferentes. Pensei em fazer da seguinte forma no html:

```
<form id="form1" method="POST"></form>
<form id="form2" method="POST"></form>
<form id="form3" method="POST"></form>

<button id="submit-forms" type="button" class="btn btn-success>
```

E no JS:

```
$("#submit-forms").on("click" function(){
    $("#form1").submit();
    $("#form2").submit();
    $("#form3").submit();
});
```

Mas não deu certo. Alguém tem alguma ideia de solução?

Comment: Onde entra o java? Nao tem nada de java nesse codigo.

Comment: Quando um form é enviado a página é "recarregada" para a `action`, então só vejo duas maneiras, junta tudo num `<form>` só e trata disso no servidor, ou envia por javascript com AJAX.

Comment: Na verdade, faz sentido sim, pois as minhas divs, criadas tanto para layout da pagina, quanto para organização não permitiram ser feito apenas um form @Sam

Comment: tem essa pequena gambi [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/wjut85er/). Basta apenas alterar a página no action do form dinâmico.

Answer (score -1):

Poderia fazer o envio via Ajax com Jquery e pegar os dados via GET (se não atrapalhar a segurança de sua aplicação):

```
var dados = '?'+$('#form1').serialize()+'&'+$('#form2').serialize()+'&'+$('#form3').serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: pagina+dados,
    success: function(response){
    },
    error: function(response){
    }
});
```

Um pouco mais sobre serialize: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score -2):

No arquivo JS tente fazer o seguinte:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(event) {
    action(event);
});

$("#form2").submit(function(event) {
    action(event);
});

$("#form3").submit(function(event) {
    action(event);
});

function action(event)
{
    //ação requerida
}
```

O Evento será disparado após clicar no botão de submit. Você não precisa por os métodos de captura do evento de "submit" dentro de um "click".